# Unexpected token c in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When sending a update in JSON to a WebAPI webservice and handling the datasource_error event I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at n.parseJSON (http://localhost:50745/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.504/jquery.min.js:4:16756)
at Xb (http://localhost:50745/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.504/jquery.min.js:4:19069)
at y (http://localhost:50745/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.504/jquery.min.js:4:22515)
at XMLHttpRequest.c (http://localhost:50745/Scripts/kendo/2016.2.504/jquery.min.js:4:26989)
```

Everything is working like it should but I don't want the event to be fired unless there is a error. I don't know how to figure out what its talking about

the response text is

```
"callback({"Divison":"roma","SupplierNumber":"054940","OpcoID":"PFRD","ProductID":"590110","ProductPack":"other","ProductDescription":"Apple Red Del X Fcy Wash","localei":0.5,"CorpEi":0.55,"corpmktei":1,"corpmkteiadj":0,"OpcoMktngEL":null,"OpcoEi":null,"spoilage":0,"processingFee":0.075})"
```

How can I figure out what is going on

This is my datasource

```
  dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/EarnedIncome/GetProducts",
                    cache: false,
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: function () {
                        return {
                            division: $("#division option:selected").text(),
                            opcoID: $("#opco option:selected").val(),
                            supplierNumber: $("#supplier option:selected").val(),
                            productID: $("#productcode").val()
                        };
                    }

                },
                update: {
                    url: "/EarnedIncome/UpdateProduct",
                    dataType: "json",
                }
                ,
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options) };
                    }
                    if (operation === "read") {
                        return {
                            division: $("#division option:selected").text(),
                            opcoID: $("#opco option:selected").val(),
                            supplierNumber: $("#supplier option:selected").val(),
                            productID: $("#productcode").val()
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            change: function (e) {
                if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                    this.sync();
                    // this.saveChanges();
                    $("#EarnedIncomeGrid .k-dirty-cell").removeClass('k-dirty-cell');

                    var popupNotification = $("#popupNotification").kendoNotification(
                            {
                                position: {
                                    top: $(document).height() / 2 + 300,
                                    right: $(document).width() / 2
                                },
                                allowHideAfter: 500,
                                stacking: "down"

                            }
                        ).data("kendoNotification");
                    var staticNotification = $("#staticNotification").kendoNotification({
                        appendTo: "#appendto"
                    }).data("kendoNotification");
                    popupNotification.show("Cell Saved", "success");
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                model: {
                    id: "ProductID",
                    fields: {
                        ProductID: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        ProductPack: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        ProductDescription: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        CorpEl: { type: "string", editable: true },
                        OpcoEL: { type: "string", editable: true },
                        OpcoMktngEL: { type: "string", editable: true },
                        spoilage: { type: "string", editable: true },
                        processingFee: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 15,
        },
```

Comment: Well, to start with, your response isn't even slightly JSON. It might be JSONP, which is an old and no longer useful twist on JSON. If that's the case, you need to pull out the object being passed to `callback`.

Comment: that's not json. It's a JSONP response wrapped up as a string. Stripping off the leading `"callback(` and trailing `)"` would give you json

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  You should try to format it as proper JSON on the server if you can.

Comment: I updated my question to include my datasource which I tell it to use JSON  how can I change that ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: Try to change it to `dataType: 'jsonp'`, since that's what the server is returning.  Or edit the server to return JSON.  You need to have the client and server agree on the data type being returned.

Comment: ah that is happening on the server

Comment: Can you edit the server-side code to have it return JSON instead of JSONP?

Comment: Yes is there an advantage to using Json over JsonP ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: JSONP is a "workaround" for doing cross-domain requests.  You needed to use it if the server did not support CORS.  JSON can be used for same-domain requests or CORS requests.  So, in your case, if it's the same-domain JSON from the server would fix it.

Comment: Thanks guys I had JSONP on the server and JSON on the client without realizing it